# Delphi EInOutError exception is not raised

Tags: delphi

I am trying to copy directory:

```
    procedure CopyBigDirWithSubdirs;
    {$IOCHECKS ON}
    begin
      try
        TDirectory.Copy(SrcPath, DstPath);
      except
        on E: EInOutError do something
      end;
    end;
```

In my case it is crucial to check disk full condition and I hoped that catching EInOutError exception would solve my problem. But as far as I could find out TDirectory methods do not notify of this condition at all. The situation is even worse because TDirectory.copy can write part of subdirs, face disk full condition and terminate, so I have to check the whole directory tree to be sure that my directory is copied properly. Does anybody know better solution?

Comment: Maybe you would have more luck with [`IFileOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-copyitem)?

Comment: Or try the [JCL CopyDirectory function](https://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:CopyDirectory)?

Comment: Not a solution but it may be worth writing a bug report to [https://quality.embarcadero.com](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{$IOCHECKS ON}` isn't relevant here. That's for legacy Pascal I/O. And likewise for `EInOutError`, you aren't ever going to get that from functions in the `IOUtils` unit.

The real problem here is that `TDirectory.Copy` is, like so much of `IOUtils`, broken by design. There appears to be no error checking whatsoever implemented in `TDirectory.Copy`. For what it is worth, the rule at my place of work is that `IOUtils` must not be used in our code.

You are going to have to either write your own code which does include some error checking, or find a third party library to do the work.

Certainly on Windows then you should use `IFileOperation` to do this. As a benefit you'll even be able to show the standard system progress dialog. And because the code is provided by the system rather than by Embarcadero, you can expect it to work.

If you require support for other platforms then you may have to work a little harder to find suitable code.

Comment: That statement about `IOUtils` should be written in stone. There's so much crap in it and I often wonder what they were thinking. The best part is that in order not to break existing users, they aren't going to fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

As using IFileOperation interface looks like most practical solution I've written the function based on it:

```
function CopyItem(const Src, Dest: string ): HRESULT;
const
  FOF_SILENT = $0004;
  FOF_NOCONFIRMATION = $0010;
  FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR = $0200;
  FOF_NOERRORUI = $0400;
  FOF_NO_UI =(FOF_SILENT or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_NOERRORUI or FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR); // don't display any UI at all
var
  lFileOperation: IFileOperation;
  psiFrom: IShellItem;
  psiTo: IShellItem;
  opAborted : longbool;
begin
  //We probably don't need to call CoInitializeEx/CoUninitialize pair as it could have been called by Delphi library
  CoInitializeEx(nil,  COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED or COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);

  // check arguments and create the IFileOperation interface,
  if (Src='') or (Dest='') then Result := E_INVALIDARG
  else Result := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOperation, nil, CLSCTX_ALL, IFileOperation, lFileOperation);

  // Set the operation flags. Turn off all UI from being shown to the user
  if Succeeded(Result) then Result := lFileOperation.SetOperationFlags(FOF_NO_UI);

  // Create IShellItem-s from the supplied source and dest paths.
  if Succeeded(Result) then Result := SHCreateItemFromParsingName(PWideChar(wideString(Src)),
                                             nil, IShellItem, psiFrom);
  if Succeeded(Result) then Result := SHCreateItemFromParsingName(PWideChar(wideString(Dest)),
                                             nil, IShellItem, psiTo);

  // This method does not copy the item, it merely declares the item to be copied
  if Succeeded(Result) then Result := lFileOperation.CopyItem(psiFrom, psiTo, nil, nil);

  // This method is called last to execute those actions that have been specified earlier
  if Succeeded(Result) then Result := lFileOperation.PerformOperations;

  // Check now if the operation was aborted by the system
  if Succeeded(Result) then
  begin
    lFileOperation.GetAnyOperationsAborted(opAborted);
    if opAborted then Result := ERROR_WRITE_FAULT;
  end;

  CoUninitialize;
end;
```

As you can see from the code the solution is not complete because in case of disc full error (my reason for all this fiddling with lFileOperation) PerformOperations returns S_OK (!!!) and I can find the error only by calling GetAnyOperationsAborted which does not specify the error condition exactly but merely sets opAborted flag. Then I have to guess the real case of abortion.